# Writing direction on seals

Tags: writing, culture, seal

I am experimenting with an [online seal generator](http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/seal.html), the text I have entered is 一千五百 and I have noticed that the characters go first from top right to bottom right, then *from bottom left to top left.* Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: NO. Here's a good introduction to [`章法`](http://www.shufazidian.com/shuji/article.php?arid=41&acid=21). You can go counterclockwise, but not clockwise, for rectangular stamps with 4 characters.

Comment: @Stan thanks for the link. I used this site before, and ended up swapping the 3rd and 4th characters myself (using MS Paint).. These two seem to work better for my purpose. http://www.purpleculture.net/chinese-seal-generator/   http://www.chinesetools.eu/tools/chinese-seals/

Comment: @leo4jc Why not just swap the input?

Comment: @DrunkenMaster Haha.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the direction when I generated the graphics. Then I didn't have internet access when I was ready to use it! LOL

Answer (score 5):

The general principle is from top to bottom, from right to left, but the format can be very flexible. For a four-character seal, there are 6 ways to arrange the characters (see picture). Seal calligraphers normally pick the arrangement that is most aesthetically pleasing, depending on how the character is written & number of strokes per character, etc. The only exception I'm aware of is for 4-character seal, the 2nd format in the picture breaks the right-left rule but that particular one has a particular name called 回文布排 ie "anti-clockwise" that is for 4-character seal only.

picture taken from http://www.shufazidian.com/shuji/article.php?acid=21&arid=41
[image]

Comment: Of course this is good, and @Stan has already linked to this page. I am still puzzled if the clockwise pattern used by the site in the description can be considered valid or not.

Comment: What about a 3 character seal? Some ten years ago I made myself a seal for my "chosen chinese name" Zhou Luyi: http://imgur.com/74lsQi6
Is it right? I made it most for fun and to stamp on some practice shufa sheets.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. It is called 竖排.

Comment: I know what 竖排 is, the proper question is if it is possible to write first from top to bottom, and then from *bottom to top*.